# double to string

Tags: c++

```
 std::string result = "Result: ";
 double min = std::numeric_limits<double>::min(); // Почему тут значение минимума 
                                                  // есть.
 result += std::to_string(min);                   // А на выходе из to_string 
                                                  // нули.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

min достаточно маленькое - 2.22507e-308 (заметье, это не отрицательное число, а чучуть больше нуля). И при [преобразовании к строке](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string), sprintf решил преобразовать в ноль (согласно формату).